# Sharing folders VMWare 12 and Windows 10. Shared folders are not found

Tags: 16.04, vmware, file-sharing, shared-folders

I'm using VMWare 12 on a Windows 10 machine to run a Ubuntu 16.04 OS. Due to some testing I need to share files using a shared folder.

So far I've enabled the folder sharing on the virtual machine, selected the folder to share (it is in the main C:/ drive on Windows) and enabled folder sharing on my private network. However, I still cannot find the shared folder under /mnt. In fact there's not even the /hgfs folder.

How can this be and how can I solve it?

In case I cannot solve it, is there a better way to share files with the host than a shared folder?

Comment: There have been reported issues with hgfs, and I gave up trying to make it work reliably.  One alternative would be to use samba, and share the file using Windows tools, and the smb client on Ubuntu to utilize the share.

Answer (score 0):

Using that source:
https://communities.vmware.com/message/2510025#2510025

I composed joined command:

sudo apt-get remove open-vm-tools; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install git; sudo git clone https://github.com/rasa/vmware-tools-patches.git; cd vmware-tools-patches; sudo ./download-tools.sh; sudo ./untar-and-patch.sh; sudo ./compile.sh

After that you will see shared folder.
Keep in mind, at the time of command executing, dozen of vmware tools different versions are download and installed and it takes around 1 hour.